# how can i verify that git fetch upstream master actually pulled changes?

Tags: git, upstream-branch

First off: I'm a relative newbie to `git` but am very familiar with `svn` (but that doesn't count anymore): 
I was told that changes were committed to master (at `83bb0af238f2d845a633a920ee647395234033a6`) and I should update my forked copy. I have set a `remote` "upstream" to master and executed a `git fetch upstream master` in my working copy. I then got the following:

```
...
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp/path/to/repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   fa3e0c9..83bb0af  master     -> upstream/master
```

and I was wondering how I can verify that the changes actually were pulled-in and that my copy now is up-to-date?

I pulled the changes into my local master copy and did `git log` to see the changes. Now the problem is, I'd expect the same comment to show up in my forked local copy too (on `git log`) but it doesn't... what went wrong I'm wondering and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can use `git log` to see the latest commits in your current local branch. If you compare to the remote, that should allow you to check to see if you have the latest. I don't know if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes, that's what I just did but the log comments d not add up :( and I'm not sure how to fix it.. I'll edit the original question...

Comment: Note that with SVN you have one "main" or "real" server, the central SVN server. With Git every repo is equally "main" or "real". So this means that if you have both `origin` and `upstream`—as is likely the case here—they can't *both* be *the* source of truth. In fact, *your* repo is your source of truth, you just copy from their repos to your `origin/*` and `upstream/*` names. You must then run a second Git command to integrate commits taken from them, if you wish.

Comment: This "must run second Git command" is why `git pull` exists. By default the second command `git pull` runs is `git merge` (the first is always `git fetch`, there's no "by default" at all here). But I always suggest that new users *avoid* pull: keep those two commands separate while you're learning. Learn what merge and rebase do, and how they affect *your* repository, which is *your* source-of-truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```

this will stash any local change, then pull the changes from remote and finally pops your stashed contents, if any.

To get the changes from your upstream

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream master
git merge upstream/master
git log
git push origin
```

Now, your upstream changes are pulled, merged and pushed to your fork (origin).

Comment: `git pull` only gets commits that wre made to my fork but this is not what I need, I need to pull in changes that were made to the upstream master branch. `git pull` won't help, I just get a `Already up-to-date`

Comment: What does `git checkout master` do exactly in this instance and why is it needed?

Comment: Just to ensure you're in your master branch in your local checkout of your fork.

Comment: Oky, I did this now and it looked like the change came in afteere doing the `git merge upstream/master` an it shows up in `git log` but not in `git status` hence, I do not need to push anything yet (as I've got unfinished changes)

Comment: git status should show [ahead N] where N no. of commts are got from your upstream.